# Thread-per-connection model

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io, blocking

Talking about the *thread-per-connection* model, each connection is supposed to have one single thread. This thread is used to read data from the stream. However, since I'm using a *blocking I/O*, I can't send anything while it's trying to read something.

Apparently Minecraft uses two threads per connection, one for reading and one for writing. Is that something I should do too or how should I be implementing this?

As far as I know, sending data also blocks, so I can't just send it from the tick thread, right?

So once again, what I want to know is:

- Should I have a read and write thread for each connection? If not, how should I implement this then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can opt for `nio` package

Comment: What's your usage scenario? You've described an implementation, but without knowing how you're going to be using these threads it's impossible to say whether it's the *appropriate* implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple ping-pong style network dialog, a single thread operating some kind of state-machine will be sufficient.

If, however, data needs to be sent and/or received asynchronously and not in direct response to the last piece of data received or sent, one thread per *direction* is sensible and not a bad solution in any way.

Non-blocking IO, as provided by Java's [`NIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/), is advantageous for high-performance, high-throughput applications like heavily loaded web servers etc. where it is not preferrable to have one or two *threads* per connection, which may total in thousands of threads running concurrently on the server. On the client side not much is to be gained by using non-blocking IO, and multi-threading is the way to go if you don't expect to maintain hundreds of connections simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to go ahead and use a thread per direction. 

I'm trying to avoid using NIO because IO is a lot simpler and it won't be necessary anyways since my game won't have more than a 100 players. Thanks!